# How does certain part of an event handler not work?

Tags: javascript, canvas, event-handling

I'm making a simple paint application as homework employing the state design pattern.
And I took a code sample from a [website](http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/) that explains free-drawing on canvas via different tools.

And the section explaining the point-based drawing is seen as below:

```
var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

var isDrawing, points = [ ];

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
};

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points.length = 0;
};
```

The part that I couldn't understand is the event handler set to *el.onmousemove*.

Afaic, the event handler keeps going on while our hand is on mouse down. So how does it achieve to draw a line that follows our cursor without clearing the canvas via the following line:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
```

Even further, the function itself doesn't make sense to me. Because it is supposed to be working thus refreshing the state non-stop. So there is no time for it to accumulate the points to be drawn for later via the following line:

```
ctx.stroke();
```

I am not sure that I could clarify the point enough for you to grasp.

Comment: Are you expecting this event to fire like "continuously"? It's not, every sensor has a minimum refresh rate, and here for mousemove, browsers will even throttle these events to the screen refresh rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
```

which occurs on every mouse movement, clears the current canvas.

What's happening here is, every time there's a mouse movement:

- The canvas is cleared
- A new coordinates object is pushed to `points` (this `points` array is *persistent* - it keeps track of all points ever visited, from the user's first mouse click)
- The 2d context creates a path over all the points that have been visited - that's what the `beginPath`, `moveTo`, and `lineTo` methods do
- The constructed path is then rendered with `ctx.stroke`, which turns the path into visible lines that can be seen by the user

> So there is no time for it to accumulate the points to be drawn for later via the following line:

Every time there's a mouse movement, a new object gets pushed to the `points` array. Once there are a couple objects in the array (or more), the

```
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
```

will then draw a line between all such points.

The only time nothing will be visible will be on the initial click, when the `points` array has only a single object (and there aren't any other points to draw a line to).

Comment: Put simply, it's redrawing the entire picture every time, not just the new line.

Comment: Why don't we see the blank canvas for a second between each new drawing? Is it so fast that we cannot perceive the state of being blank? I thought it would constitute flickering.

Comment: @ibrahimkoz Because the browser does not re-render the screen the user sees until all synchronous JavaScript has finished executing. It usually takes a handful of milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've understood utterly.